# How do I force Ubuntu to boot into initramfs?

Tags: boot, lvm, initramfs

```
root@Pavlov:/# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
```

I made the sad mistake of putting `/` on an LVM2 volume group with 3 drives.

Less than a year later one drive has failed and I need to remove it.

Consequently I have to unmount the vg and resize it to remove the failed drive! Betcha I won't make this mistake again!

Comment: You might be better off with a Live USB boot. Otherwise you might not have all tools available you need...

Comment: I don't want to do that since initramfs will assemble  the lv for me. fsck and resize2fs are part of the initramfs and thats all I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make the boot process stop in the `initramfs`, you have to add `break` to the kernel line in `grub`.
There are different stages and one can instruct to stop at a given stage. The default is `premount`, for further options and a comprehensive description refer to [man initramfs-tools](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html).

It is often a hassle to get the `grub` menu during boot, but normally <kbd>Esc</kbd> will raise it, when pressed at the right time. Maybe pressing it again and again during boot will raise your chance.
Once in the boot menu of `grub`, select the boot entry you want to boot with your <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> keys and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the entry.
Then navigate down to the line that starts with `linux` and append `break` or `break=<run-time>` to make the boot process stop in the `initramfs`.